# How to create a reference between entities in Spring Data Rest Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to build simple application with Spring Boot + Data Rest + JPA.
A have Category and Book entities with one to many relationship:

```
<!-- language-all: java -->    
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
    private Set<Book> books;

    ...getters & setters next...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;

    ...getters & setters next...
}
```

Simple repositories for each entity

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {}
```

And application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application starts successfully and I can create books and categories. 
**Q.:** How I can create and remove a references between them?

I tried solution described here: [POSTing a @OneToMany sub-resource association in Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest)
 - didn't work for me: on PUT request with *"ContentType: text/uri-list"* header I have response code 204 and no changes in the database. Looking deeper I was found the following debug message in the log:

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
Did not find handler method for [/categories/1/books]
```

This url is available only for GET requests.

**Q.:** Any ideas what is wrong in my configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To **create** a relation between book(id:1) and category(id:1):

- put request,
- media type: text/uri-list,
- data: http://localhost:8080/categories/1
- request to http://localhost:8080/books/1/category

curl example:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/categories/1" http://localhost:8080/books/1/category
```

To **remove** this relation just do a delete request to the same address

curl example:

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/books/1/category
```

And to answer your 2nd question as well: your configuration looks good and I have tested this example on your code.

Comment: This solution works for me, thank you! 
Is it possible to add several books to one category in one go?

Comment: I have tried reversing that put (or post) request without success yet. I've got no exception and my behaviour is matching the bug description you found.